# Why don't dashboard widgets display custom dimension data for dates other than the current day in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, event-tracking, analytics-events, custom-dimensions

I currently send events to my Google Analytics account with custom dimensions and custom metrics. I use the measurement protocol to send these events.

I set a Dashboard with a widget per custom dimension and metric and it displays me all I need.

The problem is, only "today"'s value is displayed and when I pick another range of date the widgets display no data.

But I know there should be data displayed because in the Behaviour > Event section I can see it.

One other thing is weird: if I choose to display from Yesterday to Today, all widgets are empty, but if I choose just today widgets display data.

It does look like a bug, do someone knows more about it ?